# WCF REST Service: Method parameter (object) is always null

Tags: rest, wcf, datacontract, datamember

I've seen a few similar questions on here, but none have worked for this particular problem.

I have a WCF Rest web service and its working ok for GET. One method is a POST, and whenever i call it passing the json parameter, the parameter that is passed is null when the method runs on the web server.

Here is the code:

**Client Call:**

```
   public async Task Test()
    {
        HttpClient client;
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 2147483646;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        ContactParameter cp = new ContactParameter();
        cp.ApptDateFrom = DateTime.Now;
        cp.ApptDateTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        cp.Code = "00";
        cp.Type = Enums.ContactType.Person;
        cp.Status = string.Empty;

        string RestUrl = "http://localhost:61919/data.svc/GetBooked";
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(RestUrl, string.Empty));

        JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
        };

        //json string = {"Code":"00","ApptDateTo":"2017-11-22T14:02:01.8758558+00:00","ApptDateFrom":"2017-11-21T14:02:01.8718458+00:00","Type":67,"Status":"A"}
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cp);

        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    }
```

**WCF Web service contract:**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetBooked")]

    List<Contact> GetBooked(ContactParameter contactParameter);
```

**Contact Parameter type**

```
namespace CatService.Types
    {
        [DataContract (Name = "contactParameter")]
        public class ContactParameter
            {
                [DataMember(Name = "Code")]
                public string Code { get; set; }
                [DataMember(Name = "ApptDateTo")]
                public DateTime ApptDateTo { get; set; }
                [DataMember(Name = "ApptDateFrom")]
                public DateTime ApptDateFrom { get; set; }
                [DataMember(Name = "Type")]
                public Enums.Enums.Type Type { get; set; }
                [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
                public string Status { get; set; }

            }
   }
```

I've tried changing the WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, but then i get a StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'.
If i try a test method which accepts just a string, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same problem. I suggest ,you should try your Post method on another console app. Because of POST method not to be on URL.

Answer (score 0):

This was a datetime issue, i didnt implement the answer on a previous post. Basicaly:

```
JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
        };
```

Then when you serialize....

```
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonString, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```